# vba webbrowser and external javascript loading

Tags: vba

I manually have a constructed web page in a string for displaying in WebBrowser control (part of code)

```
    ie.Document.clear

        str = "<!DOCTYPE html>" & vbCrLf _
            & "<html>" & vbCrLf _
            & "<head>" 

& vbCrLf _
        & "<script src=""http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js""></script>" & vbCrLf _

            & "<script>" & vbCrLf _
     & "$(function() {" _
    & "$( ""#dialog"" ).dialog();" _
    & "});" _
    & "</script>" & vbCrLf _
            & "</head><body>" & vbCrLf _

ie.Document.write str
ie.Document.Close
```

After many hours of investigation, I finally concluded that JQuery external *.js script isn't loaded at time that WB parser reaches the dialog() function. Even I put the file locally (with local path) isn't loaded.

The IE error is "The value of property $ is null or undefined...".

The HTML (constructed) code is OK because I did a very simple test. I saved the WB page source via right click -> page source, I saved locally as *.htm and back in MSACCESS, I use navigate WB's method

```
ie.Navigate "file:///V:/...file.htm"
```

And this is working just fine.

So the question is why

```
ie.Document.write str  -> not working
ie.Navigate -> works
```

I need the first method since I use WinHTTP to make a request, take some real page, parse and finally display in WB.

Of course, I could manipulate emulation from
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION which btw works but this will fall into several problems on other machines where I cannot have access to registry.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post the final rendered HTML verbatim, as well as look at what your browser's F12 network tools say is happening.

Comment: Since loading the file locally works, you could write out the content to a file in the user's Temp folder and load it from there.

Comment: @Tim Williams nice, I was about to write to TMP and load from there, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got It! I noticed accidentally that right click refresh will load the JS :)
Since I spent many hours to dig, here is the trick in case someone will need:

```
ie.Silent = True           ' <-- supress any JS warnins
ie.Document.clear
ie.Document.write str
ie.Refresh    ' <-- this will load the JQuery just fine
```

I really don't understant WTF Microsoft still use default ancient IE in emulated stuff including it's own products like Office?!

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to get it working after reviewing your answer. You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the OP's answer I concluded that refreshing the WebBrowser does indeed load JQuery.

A few notes:

- "" is required
- `WebBrowser.Document.Clear` isn't needed
- `WebBrowser.Navigate` or `WebBrowser.Navigate2` can be used
- `WebBrowser.Refresh` or `WebBrowser.Refresh2` can be used

### Test

```
Dim HTML As String
With CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
    .Append_3 "<!DOCTYPE html>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "<HTML>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "<HEAD>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "<SCRIPT src=""http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js""></SCRIPT>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "<SCRIPT>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "$(function() {" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "$( ""#test"" ).css( ""border"", ""3px solid red"" );"
    .Append_3 "});"
    .Append_3 "</SCRIPT>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "</HEAD>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "<BODY>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "<DIV id=""test"">Hey</DIV>"
    .Append_3 "</BODY>" & vbCrLf
    .Append_3 "</HTML>" & vbCrLf
    HTML = .ToString
End With

With WebBrowser1
    .navigate "About:Blank"
    .Silent = True
    .Document.Write HTML
    .Refresh
End With
```